# Eloquent - multiple 'when' conditions in query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I create query dependent for multiple parameters. When controller function get for example 'price' and 'status' parameter I want to return results based on that two parameters.

When I use one parameter everything works well.

There is example of my controller.

```
 $productList = Product::
                    where([
                        ['lat', '>', $calculateDistanceDifference->getData()->latDifferenceBottom], 
                        ['lat', '<', $calculateDistanceDifference->getData()->latDifferenceTop], 
                        ['lng', '>', $calculateDistanceDifference->getData()->lngDifferenceBottom], 
                        ['lng', '<', $calculateDistanceDifference->getData()->lngDifferenceTop]
                    ])
                    ->when(request('price') !== "", function ($q) {
                        if(request('price') === "0-20"){
                            return $q->where([['price', '>', 0], ['price', '<=', 20]]);
                        }else if(request('price') === "21-50"){
                            return $q->where([['price', '>', 20], ['price', '<=', 50]]);
                        }else if(request('price') === "51-100"){
                            return $q->where([['price', '>', 50], ['price', '<=', 100]]);
                        }else if(request('price') === "100-200"){
                            return $q->where([['price', '>', 100], ['price', '<=', 200]]);
                        }else if(request('price') === "201+"){
                            return $q->where('price', '>', 200);
                        }
                    })
                    ->when(request('status') !== "", function ($q) {
                        if(request('status') === "new"){
                            return $q->where('status', 0);
                        }else if(request('status') === "old"){
                            return $q->where('status', 1);
                        }
                    })
                    ->when(request('active') !== "", function ($q) {
                        if(request('active') == true){

                            return $q->where('state', 0);
                        }else{
                            var_dump(request('active'));
                            return $q->where('state', 1);
                        }
                    })
                    ->with('productPhotos')
                    ->with('categories')
                    ->with('users')
                    ->get();
```

How can I avoid return statements and return result after all transformations?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me: why do you want to avoid return statements inside the when() functions? that's the way they work!. What you get as result now and what do you want as result?

Answer (score 0):

You can split and merge the query by if/else or any programming statement.

For example

```
$productList = Product::select('*');

if (request('price') !== ""){
    if(request('price') === "0-20"){ 
       $productList = $productList->where('price', '>', 0)->where('price', '<=', 20);
    }
    //any other conditions that you want to handle....
}

if (request('status') !== ""){
    if(request('status') === "new){ 
       $productList = $productList->where('status', '=', 0);
    }
    //any other conditions that you want to handle....
}

      $productList = $productList
                    ->with('productPhotos')
                    ->with('categories')
                    ->with('users')
                    ->get();
```

Hope this help.